# Wikipedia table scraping using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape tables from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population). I wrote a table scraper that downloads a table and saves it as a pandas data frame.

This is the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import urllib2

headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0' }
req = urllib2.Request('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population', None, headers)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml') # Parse the HTML as a string
print soup

# Create an object of the first object 
table = soup.find("table", {"class":"wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"})
print table

rank=[]
country=[]
pop=[]
date=[]
per=[]
source=[]

for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    col=row.find_all('td')
    col1=col[0].string.strip()
    rank.append(col1)
    col2=col[1].string.strip()
    country.append(col2)
    col3=col[2].string.strip()
    pop.append(col2)
    col4=col[3].string.strip()
    date.append(col4)
    col5=col[4].string.strip()
    per.append(col5)
    col6=col[5].string.strip()
    source.append(col6)

columns={'Rank':rank,'Country':country,'Population':pop,'Date':date,'Percentage':per,'Source':source}
# Create a dataframe from the columns variable
df = pd.DataFrame(columns)
df
```

But it is not downloading the table. The problem is in this section

```
table = soup.find("table", {"class":"wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"})
print table
```

where output is `None`

Comment: Wikipedia has a perfectly good API, why are you scraping the pages?

Comment: I am just learning about webpage scraping using python and I am using wikipedia as a test page

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is no such element on that page. The main table has `"class":"wikitable sortable"` but not the `jquery-tablesorter`.

Make sure you know what element you are trying to select and check if your program sees the same elements you see, then make your selector.

Comment: I dont know but in my system it shows like this `<table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter" style="text-align:right">`

Comment: In your web browser, or also in the html your code gets? Check `html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()` and see if it also contains the `<table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter" style="text-align:right">`

Comment: yeah you are correct after parsing through urlib2 it has become "class":"wikitable sortable" and can scrap the table but still I cant isolate values from table html

Answer (score 0):

The docs says you need to specify multiple classes like so:

```
soup.find("table", class_="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter")
```

Also, consider using requests instead of urllib2.